# Django CompileError: File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/variables

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, compiler-errors, bootstrap-sass

I am currently working on the `cadasta` - an open source organisation's -  Django project.
They require you to run their platform in a virtual machine (`virtualbox`) using `vagrant`.

As I enter their repository, and run their server using `./runserver`, I am all of a sudden getting a `CompileError` which says:

`File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/variables. Parent style sheet: /vagrant/cadasta/core/static/css/_variables.scss.
on line 74 of core/static/css/_variables.scss
@import "bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/variables";`

Following this link: https://github.com/jrief/djangocms-cascade/issues/130,
I found that `libsass` is already installed, and so I tried installing `bootstrap-sass` inside the VM, but it did no good. Everything was working fine until I renamed the cadasta-platform directory (i.e their github repo that I cloned, and so the main project is included inside this folder only.) and refreshed. I even tried running the server again, but couldn't get through this error. I suppose renaming the directory shouldn't be the cause?

I have no clue on how to proceed. Please help.

**EDIT**: After renaming the project folder to the same name solved this error. If anyone would ever like to answer this question, please explain why renaming the project directory produces an error like this? As I believe, I think renaming should not be an issue?

Comment: I am currently through this error. I don't know why, but renaming the directory again to the same name did the trick. I wouldn't be answering my own question because I actually don't know the cause of why is this even happening. If anyone would like to answer this question, please explain in your answer, as to why renaming the project directory results in this error.